# google storage: restrict svc account bucket access

Tags: java, rest, google-cloud-storage

Im hoping to use the API to create a svc account that has RO access to a single bucket. I'll be putting log files on a per-account basis into each bucket and want to restrict access between buckets.

Is the google api / IAM granular enough to do this? It will have to be via REST requests as Im dealing with some legacy Java that has old guava dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the API.

First, create a service account according to [Creating and Managing Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).

Then, grant the service account the storage.objectViewer role (as described in [Cloud Storage IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles)) for that bucket, as described in [Granting Roles to Service Accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource).

Answer (score 1):

You can find documentation for updating bucket ACLs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-bucket-acls).

You can also use the [Google Cloud Storage Java client library](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java), specifically the [Storage.createAcl(String bucket, Acl acl)](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.32.0/apidocs/com/google/cloud/storage/Storage.html#createAcl-java.lang.String-com.google.cloud.storage.Acl-) method.

The code would look like:

```
storageService.createAcl("BucketName", Acl.of(new Acl.User("serviceAccount@Email"), Acl.Role.OWNER));
```